# Making network /tower coverage map in Mapbox?

Tags: mapbox

I am new to mapping and currently I am trying to make a map showing coverage of a network provider here in my country. The map I am trying to achieve should look similar to that at http://www.imore.com/best-us-iphone-carrier-2014.

I already have the latitude and longitude coordinates of the tower locations in CSV format and have so far managed to plot the markers in TileMill (ideally I want to show coverage as opposed to markers). I have also downloaded Mapbox studio and OSGEo4W under the assumption that I might have to convert the data into another format.

I can't seem to find any comprehensive tutorials for this, all I see for Mapbox is OpenStreetMaps, terrain, markers, shapefiles etc.

I have also attached an image of what I am trying to achieve [image]

Comment: judging from the research I have done it seems I might need other software as well . Correct me If I am wrong but I doubt tilemill , mapbox  and a csv can help me achieve this? I read something about reprojection and tiff files etc I am not entirely sure

Comment: Might be as easy as plotting each marker with a reasonable radius and without border. This would result in a map like above.

Comment: @bugmenot123  `Map {
//background-color:#000;
  
}

#countries {
  ::outline {
    line-color: #000;
    line-width: 1;
    line-join: round;
  }

}

#vodacomgsm {
  polygon-fill:#b22f3b;
  marker-width:500px;
  marker-fill:#b22f3b;
  marker-allow-overlap:true;
  marker-fill-opacity :1; 

  polygon-opacity:1;
  [zoom > 8]{marker-width:40px}  
   [zoom > 10]{marker-width:60px}  
   [zoom > 12]{marker-width:80px}  
   [zoom > 14]{marker-width:100px}  
   [zoom > 16]{marker-width:120px}  
   [zoom > 18]{marker-width:140px}  
   [zoom > 20]{marker-width:160px} 
}

Comment: the above gives me huge markers on top of each other

Comment: @bugmenot123 I understand what u are saying however these markers are clustered so  when I zoom in on one they will seperate. Should I even be using markers

Comment: You did not mention zooming earlier, you linked to some static whole-country maps. Specify exactly what you have in mind.

Comment: @bugmenot123 the markers are clustered and I am able to zoom in and isolate each one .

Comment: @bugmenot123 did u see my comment

Comment: Yes but I am not sure if that is what happens or what you want to happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35337/discussion-between-zidane-and-bugmenot123).

Comment: Hey zidane, I'd be glad to help out with your interesting question if @bugmenot123 hasn't helped you yet.